# Australian - living overseas - freelancer, digital nomad - income tax

Tags: income-tax, working-abroad, sole-proprietorship

I am an Australian resident and just about to head off to travel Asia for the next year or two.

I would like to become self-employed with an Australian ABN and work as a freelancer (digital nomad) copywriter/editor while I'm travelling.

I will be freelancing mainly for Australian companies, but also hoping to have clients from other countries than Australia.

How should I go about my income and income tax. Can I freelance on an aussie ABN and pay income tax in Australia?

Comment: Be careful of working full time while abroad, even on online projects; you may run the risk of being deemed by the country you're passing through, to be working without a proper visa.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. You've got a point, but that would only happen if I either had full time physical employment in the country i'm visiting or working online for the client that resides in the country I'm visiting, correct?

I don't think I can get deemed me for being self employed in Australia and working for an Australian client based in Australia or US or Europe while i'm travelling. 
As long as it's not a client based in the country i'm visiting. Correct?

Comment: Depending on the country you're in, no, you are not correct. You do **not** need to have physical employment [full time or otherwise] to be considered working with respect to a visa, depending on that country's own laws. This is a very complex issue and you should see expert advice for each particular country you are visiting.